# How to recreate this PHP code in Python?

Tags: php, python, http, forms, automation

I've found a PHP script that lets me do what I asked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922148/how-to-make-mechanize-not-fail-with-forms-on-this-page) SO question.  I can use this just fine, but out of curiosity I'd like to recreate the following code in Python.

I can of course use urllib2 to get the page, but I'm at a loss on how to handle the cookies since mechanize (tested with Python 2.5 and 2.6 on Windows and Python 2.5 on Ubuntu...all with latest mechanize version) seems to break on the page.  How do I do this in python?

```
require_once "HTTP/Request.php";

$req = &new HTTP_Request('https://steamcommunity.com');
$req->setMethod(HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_POST);

$req->addPostData("action", "doLogin");
$req->addPostData("goto", "");

$req->addPostData("steamAccountName", ACC_NAME);
$req->addPostData("steamPassword", ACC_PASS);

echo "Login: ";

$res = $req->sendRequest();
if (PEAR::isError($res))
  die($res->getMessage());

$cookies = $req->getResponseCookies();
if ( !$cookies )
  die("fail\n");

echo "pass\n";

foreach($cookies as $cookie)
  $req->addCookie($cookie['name'],$cookie['value']);
```

Comment: @Beau Martinez To quote the topic in the freenode #python channel "it's too early to use python 3.x"

Comment: Beau, 3.x has a lot of inconsistencies (take a look at wsgiref for example). It's easy to move from 2.x to 3.x (using 2to3) but there's no way to easily go the other way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to monkut's answer, but a little more concise.

```
import urllib, urllib2

def steam_login(username,password):
    data = urllib.urlencode({
      'action': 'doLogin',
      'goto': '',
      'steamAccountName': username,
      'steamPassword': password,
    })
    request = urllib2.Request('https://steamcommunity.com/',data)
    cookie_handler = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(cookie_handler)
    response = opener.open(request)
    if not 200 <= response.code < 300:
        raise Exception("HTTP error: %d %s" % (response.code,response.msg))
    else:
        return cookie_handler.cookiejar
```

It returns the cookie jar, which you can use in other requests. Just pass it to the `HTTPCookieProcessor` constructor.

monkut's answer installs a global `HTTPCookieProcessor`, which stores the cookies between requests. My solution does not modify the global state.

Comment: +1 to both your and monkut's answers... they'd be perfect combined :-)

Comment: Nice, I wasn't familiar with the urllib2.Request object.  This maps better to Therms PHP.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with PHP, but this may get you started.
I'm installing the opener here which will apply it to the urlopen method. If you don't want to 'install' the opener(s) you can use the opener object directly.   (opener.open(url, data)).

Refer to:
http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html?highlight=urllib2#urllib2.install_opener

```
import urlib2
import urllib

# 1 create handlers
cookieHandler = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor() # Needed for cookie handling
redirectionHandler = urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler() # needed for redirection

# 2 apply the handler to an opener                                                  
opener = urllib2.build_opener(cookieHandler, redirectionHandler)

# 3. Install the openers
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

# prep post data
datalist_tuples = [ ('action', 'doLogin'),
                    ('goto', ''),
                    ('steamAccountName', ACC_NAME),
                    ('steamPassword', ACC_PASS)

                   ]
url = 'https://steamcommunity.com'
post_data = urllib.urlencode(datalist_tuples)
resp_f = urllib2.urlopen(url, post_data)
```

Comment: +1 to both your and MizardX's answers... they'd be perfect combined :-)